# Python 3.8 datetime date comparison not work between "internal generated date" and imported date

Tags: python, python-3.x, date, datetime

I'm trying to compare the actual date with externally generated date, always generated from datetime but in another script and saved in a txt file.
This is the code:

```py
import datetime
datin = datetime.datetime.today()

with open('date.txt', 'r') as mydate:
    mdate = mydate.read()
datex = datetime.datetime.strptime(mdate, '%d-%m-%Y')

if datin.date == datex.date:
    print('=')
else:
    print('!=')

print(datin.strftime('%d-%m-%Y'))
print(datex.strftime('%d-%m-%Y'))
```

this is the txt file:

```
03-07-2020
```

**(the same date I'm testing the script)**

should return `=` but return `!=`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `datin.date()` is a function. You need to call it. `if datin.date() == datex.date():`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a slight error in that you are accessing the method of the date objects instead of calling the method.
You can find this out by trying to print
`datin.date` versus `datin.date()`

Here is the corrected code that runs as expected:

```
import datetime
datin = datetime.datetime.today()


mdate = '03-07-2020'
datex = datetime.datetime.strptime(mdate,"%d-%m-%Y")

print(datin.date())
print(datex.date())
if datin.date() == datex.date():
    print("=")
else:
    print("!=")

print (datin.strftime("%d-%m-%Y"))
print(datex.strftime("%d-%m-%Y"))
```